# PHP: Call PHP Script with parameters through URL then redirect back to calling page

Tags: php

Is there a way to call another webpage with something like header() but then immediately go back to the calling file? I need to do this without entering any code into the called webpage's file. Essentially, I want to call another script using the URL to pass in parameters. Is this possible or is it useless?

Comment: Once you pass control to the final page using `header` redirect then you no longer have control over the flow, you cant force to go back. You can however call that page using `file_get_contents` or `cURL` and process the result and go back to the page that called your page.

Comment: If you do not want the users diverted to this page, and simply only want parameters passed to the other webpage then I would consider using a `cURL` request as apposed to the `header()` function.

Comment: Is this other webpage on the same server / domain as the originating page? Something like include() / require() could work or an ajax request. Are you trying to receive anything from the called webpage?

Comment: Do you need to get some data from the page?
Or just call it to start a process?
Maybe you need something like a `cURL` call

Comment: I don't need to receive any information from the called webpage. I just want it to execute the script (using HTML rather than including the file) then refresh the current page.

Answer (score 0):

If you attempt a redirect using a location header:

```
header('Location: /some/other/path');
```

The currently executing script does not immediately exit on this line. The redirect will not be processed until the response is sent to the client, at which point your currently executing script has finished. This means you cannot do anything with a location header other than request that the client perform a redirect after your current script is done executing and the full response has been sent to the client. A common suggestion when using the location header is to immediately exit your currently executing script, because sending any output to the client besides headers will cause the redirect to fail, but this is merely a suggestion.

If you'd like to make a request and do something with the response within your current runtime, or simply continue on after the request has been completed, use `cURL`, `file_get_contents` or some other method to make the request:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php